# ManagementException was Caught: Invalid class

Tags: vb.net

I have the following Function intended to identify the username of the user who started a specific process:

```
 Private Function GetProcessAssociatedUserID(ByVal processName As String) As String
    Dim user(1) As String

    Try
        Dim query As New SelectQuery(processName)
        Dim searcher As New System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(query)
        For Each process As ManagementObject In searcher.Get()
            process.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", CType(user, Object()))
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    Return user(0)

End Function
```

However somewhere in the ForEach initiation i'm getting this "ManagementException was Caught: Invalid class" exception thrown into my catch block. I've been in through debug but still cant work out what is. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You never actually named the WMI class you want to use.  So sure, it is wrong, you need Win32_Process.  Use the [WMI Code Creator utility](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572) to get this right, you can experiment with queries and let it auto-generate the code you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it accomplishing this way

```
Private Function GetProcessAssociatedUserID(ByVal processName As String) As String
    Dim query = "Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = """ + processName + """"
    Dim searcher = New ManagementObjectSearcher(query)
    Dim processList = searcher.Get()    
    For Each mObj As ManagementObject In processList
        Dim argList As String() = {String.Empty, String.Empty}
        Dim returnVal = Convert.ToInt32(mObj.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", argList))
        If returnVal = 0 Then
            Return argList(1) + "\\" + argList(0)
        End If
    Next
    Return ""
End Function
```

This snippet works with .NET Framework 3.5 and above. For more details you may refer [using-managementobjectsearcher-in-systemmanagement-is-getting-compiling-errors](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f6b445df-e761-4286-9e10-1cca19cae523/using-managementobjectsearcher-in-systemmanagement-is-getting-compiling-errors?forum=csharpgeneral)